# How can I break the corrupted rock?

Tags: terraria

I decided it was time to investigate the corruption, but I can't break the corrupted rock (or whatever it is that looks like rock inside the corrupted area). My silver pickaxe or bombs simply don't do anything to it.

How can I break it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are referring to [Ebonstone](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Ebonstone), according to wiki, you can destroy it using a [Nightmare Pickaxe](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Nightmare_Pickaxe) (or [better](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Pickaxes)), [Dynamite](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Dynamite), or purify it first using [Purification Powder](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Purification_Powder) and then mine it normally.

Comment: Oh, so not bombs, only dynamite. Thx, thought my pickaxe was to weak but the non-working bombs confused me :)

Comment: @Let_Me_Be Bombs should work fine (although they will obviously blow up less of it than dynamite)

Comment: @Justin Bombs work now, but at the time of the question they didn't work.

Comment: Dynamite is still a better bet anyway. You'll be pecking away at it with grenades.

Answer (score 1):

It actually is breakable using Bombs. It's just not possible using Grenades.

Answer (score -1):

if you have the *Merchant*, buy a **Bug Net**, catch *Critters* with it (if they say they can be used as **Bait**, keep them) make a **Reinforced Fishing Pole** with **Iron** or **Lead**, go to the ocean, and fish, you might (eventually, just be patent, it you aren't, go my other way), after a while, get a fish called a **Reaver Shark**, equal in level to the **Molten pickaxe**, which you get from **Hellstone Bars**, from **Obsidian** (water and lava mixed) and **Hellsotone**, (from the *Underworld*), both which you have to mine with a **Nightmare Pickaxe**, requiring breaking the **Ebonstone** from the *Corruption* (the rock you are talking about), breaking the three purple orbs (called **Shadow Orbs**, killing the boss you have summoned (called the *Eater of Worlds*), and making it from the **Shadow Scales** and **Demonite** he drops.

```
Making Community Wiki, from Yharon
```

Answer (score -3):

You might be using grenades they don't destroy anything so that's use less.
You can use bombs or grenades to destroy the ebonstone and also the nightmare pick or better.