# Why are these blocks unbreakable?

Tags: terraria

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I break the corrupted rock?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22947/how-can-i-break-the-corrupted-rock)

I'm in the corruption, and I noticed that the rock here is indestructible. Why?

[image: Unbreakable rock]

*The block type I'm facing can't be destroyed*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That is [ebonstone](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Ebonstone_Block) and it can only be broken with higher tier pickaxes.

From your screenshot, it looks like you have either an iron pickaxe or a silver pickaxe, neither of which are strong enough to destroy the ebonstone.

It is possible to destroy before you obtain the higher tier pickaxes using one of these methods:

- [Dynamite](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Dynamite)

  - You can find dynamite in chests, or buy it from the [Demolitionist](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Demolitionist) if you have managed to get him to move in yet
- [Purification powder](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Purification_Powder)

  - You can buy this from the [Dryad](http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Dryad) if you have managed to get her to move in yet; after using the powder on the ebonstone, you will be able to mine the stone normally with your current pickaxe

Comment: Careful with dynamite in the Corruption.  Breaking Shadow Orbs, while awesome, after 3 spawns a nasty boss.

Comment: If you want a picaxe that can mine Ebonstone, you will need, at least a Nightmare Pickaxe. It is ranking just above the Gold Picaxe, and it can mine any type of block. More info on how to get it here: http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Nightmare_Pickaxe

Comment: Or take a peek at the other wiki :) http://wiki.terrariaonline.com/Nightmare_Pickaxe